# Dynamic table Css property using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Table Css property not align if i am giving css in jquery.
First i am just giving Html

```
<tr id="trCustomLabel">
 <td class="font12" style="border: 0px; width: 8%;padding-left: 10px;" id="tdlab">Custom Label</td>
 <td class="font11" style="border: 0px; text-align: center; width: 2%;" id="tdlab1">:</td>
 <td class="font12" style="border: 0px; padding-top: 0px; width: 55%;" id="tdlab2"> <div><input type="checkbox" id="chkRestoreLocation"/> Create new label for restore</div></td>
</tr>
```

After that i am controling the element in jquery

```
if (currentID == "tabGmail") {$('tr[id$=trCustomLabel]').css("display", "block");}
if (currentID == "tabDrive") {   $('tr[id$=trCustomLabel]').css("display", "block");}
if (currentID == "tabContact") {$('tr[id$=trCustomLabel]').css("display", "none");}
```

Output : 
[image]

Comment: it's better to add a dynamic class instead of the actual css

Comment: @Michiel Yes i am control the element while tab click its getting mis align the <tr>

Answer (score 0):

Please make this changes in your code.

```
    if (currentID == "tabGmail") {
       $('tr#trCustomLabel').css("display", "block");
    }
    if (currentID == "tabDrive") {  
       $('tr#trCustomLabel').css("display", "block");
    }
    if (currentID == "tabContact") {
       $('tr#trCustomLabel').css("display", "none");
    }
```

Comment: if you just want to hide and show the elements, then use `.hide()` and `.show()` functions

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (currentID) {
    case tabGmail:
        $('tr#trCustomLabel').css("display", "block");
        break;
    case tabDrive:
        $('tr#trCustomLabel').css("display", "block");
        break;
    case tabContact:
        $('tr#trCustomLabel').css("display", "none");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go on a limb and guess you have a bunch of buttons that control the display of table rows. I'm also assuming that `trCustomLabel` is a placeholder (because you're not really using the same id various times, right? That kinda defies the point of an id. Use a class if you want to target a few different elements).

To cut down on code lines and also make it a tad more generic, I suggest you do it like this:

```
// define what points to where
var controllers = {
    'tabGmail'  : 'trGmailLabel',
    'tabDrive'  : 'trDriveLabel',
    'tabContact': 'trContactLabel'
}

// toggle the required element
if (controllers.hasOwnProperty(currentID)) {
    $('tr#' + controllers[currentID]).toggle();
}
```